# Extend filesystem after hdd-cloning 32GB to 500GB

Tags: server, partitioning, 18.04, hard-drive, filesystem

Before anyone marks this as a duplicate, please bear with me - I'm pulling my hair for a good amount of time and went through all the other questions but I can't seem to find an answer coping with the exact same problem.

I'm on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS. I changed a 32GB SSD to a 500GB HDD by dd-cloning it and fixed the partition-table and extended the partition size with parted.

Now, I want to make use of all new available space. I did

```
sudo vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/sda3
```

but I get "Can't open /dev/sda3 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?"

I guess I'm not seeing the bigger picture here because I lack the experience in this context.

Here's some more output, looking for a bit of input to help me understand what's going on. Thanks!

```
sudo partprobe /dev/sda3
```

> sudo partprobe /dev/sda3
>   Error: Partition(s) 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64 on /dev/sda3 have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use.  As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use.  You should reboot now before making further changes.

A reboot doesn't affect this message.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

> Disk /dev/loop0: 91 MiB, 95408128 bytes, 186344 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop1: 91.1 MiB, 95494144 bytes, 186512 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/loop2: 89.5 MiB, 93835264 bytes, 183272 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors Units:
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disklabel type: gpt Disk identifier:
>   E63DDDF3-F746-41FF-8E31-611F4891E2A8
>
> Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type /dev/sda1     2048 
>   4095      2048     1M BIOS boot /dev/sda2     4096   2101247   2097152
>   1G Linux filesystem /dev/sda3  2101248 976562500 974461253 464.7G
>   Linux filesystem
>
> Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 12.6 GiB, 13463715840 bytes,
>   26296320 sectors Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size
>   (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal):
>   4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

```
sudo pvscan
```

> PV /dev/sda3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [28.81 GiB / 16.27 GiB free] 
>   Total: 1 [28.81 GiB] / in use: 1 [28.81 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

```
sudo vgscan
```

> Reading volume groups from cache.   Found volume group "ubuntu-vg"
>   using metadata type lvm2

```
sudo lvscan
```

> ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [<12.54 GiB] inherit

```
df
```

> Filesystem                        1K-blocks    Used Available Use%
>   Mounted on udev                                3987928       0
>   3987928   0% /dev tmpfs                                803708    2664 
>   801044   1% /run /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  12874848 6635588
>   5656332  54% / tmpfs                               4018532       0
>   4018532   0% /dev/shm tmpfs                                  5120
>   4      5116   1% /run/lock tmpfs                               4018532
>   0   4018532   0% /sys/fs/cgroup /dev/loop0
>   93184   93184         0 100% /snap/core/6350 /dev/loop2
>   91648   91648         0 100% /snap/core/6130 /dev/loop1
>   93312   93312         0 100% /snap/core/6259 /dev/sda2
>   999320  208868    721640  23% /boot tmpfs
>   803704       8    803696   1% /run/user/1000

Comment: You can't make changes to partitions that are mounted and in use.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't unmount sda..

sudo umount -l /dev/sda3
umount: /dev/sda3: not mounted.

When I check for processes that use sda I get no output:
fuser -m -v /dev/sda3